# what tree generation algorithm is used to create DT, ID3? C4.5, CART?

Tags: machine-learning

**By default** what tree generation algorithm is used to create decision tree? D3? C4.5, CART?

Comment: What tool are you using? You should check that documentation.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I know. But normally by default decision tree uses specific tool

Comment: You use the tool. If you are using Python you could choose scikit-learn, h2o, spark, R (and its many tree packages), xgboost, etc.  You could be using an R tree package or again Spark, h2o, xgboost or call Python tool. You could use Java and some of its tools.

Comment: So, which one normally python utilized in DT? D3? C4.5, CART?

Comment: Python is a programming language. Which ML or Decision Tree tool are you using from Python. scikit, h2o, spark, R, SPSS, Salford, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're using the scikit-learn library, the DT algorithm implemented is an optimized version of CART. [From the documentation:](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#tree-algorithms-id3-c4-5-c5-0-and-cart)

> scikit-learn uses an optimised version of the CART algorithm; however, scikit-learn implementation does not support categorical variables for now.